# View.startAnimation() with Robolectric 3.2.1 result in endless loop

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am doing some UT with **Robolectric3.2.1**. During **onCreate()** of my **TestActivity**, I start an **anmation** like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  ...
    mImageView.startAnimation(createAnim());
  ...
}
```

the method that creat an animationSet:

```
private AnimationSet createAnim(){
    AnimationSet scaleAndAlphaAnim = (AnimationSet)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.radar_scale_alpha_anim);
    scaleAndAlphaAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    for (Animation anim : scaleAndAlphaAnim.getAnimations()) {
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setDuration(1500L);
    }
    return scaleAndAlphaAnim;
}
```

and the animation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <scale
    android:fromXScale="0.75"
    android:fromYScale="0.75"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.5"
    android:toYScale="1.5"/>
  <alpha
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

after I run code:

```
Robolectric.setupActivity(TestActivity.class);
```

The main thread gets stuck into endless loop at **mImageView.startAnimation(createAnim())**.But the code performs well on my real devices. Now I am confused. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: I would create issue on Robolectric github

Comment: The phenomenon disappear after I add **scaleAndAlphaAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE)**. With some more debugging, I found that in method AnimationRunner.run() of ShadowView , **animation.getRepeatCount() == Animation.INFINITE** is regarded as one of the conditions to break the loop, while the default repeatCount of Animation being 0.